# Cremona SV-1220 missing sound post?

Tags: violin, repair

I purchased a Cremona SV-1220 violin today at a yard sale. It didn’t have any strings on it. I purchased some at a local guitar shop that had some in stock. I was watching a video on the internet about how to string the violin. It mentioned not to take off all the strings at once because the sound post could come lose and that would require a repair by a professional.

I don’t see a sound post in this violin. Do all violins have a sound post? If so I guess it is gone. It does look to me however that there is a support on the left side. Perhaps this model does not use a sound post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, all violins have a sound post.  It is positioned under the right foot of the bridge.  There's also a reinforcing strip of wood called the Bass Bar glued under the left foot.   This won't fall off if there's no string tension pushing  the bridge down, but the sound post very likely will.  And it seems yours has.

It's only a glorified bit of dowel.  Supplying and fitting a replacement is a skilled job, but not a big one. It will probably cost about the same as the set of strings you bought.